# Java variable value as new variable name

Tags: java, variables, naming-conventions

I was wondering if in Java there was any way to give a new variable a name which is the value of another variable. The below code is an non working example of what I'm trying to do.

```
int a = 0;
while(true){
    String (a) = "newValue";
    a = a + 1;
}
```

or

```
String b = "newVariableName";
int (b) = 1;
```

Thank for any help given.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? Why do you need such functionality?

Comment: Almost guaranteed that you don't actually need or want that. It's an XY problem. *Edit.* You should also take to heart the Zero-One-Many rule of programming.

Comment: Java doesn't work that way, and not only that a variable name is a lot less important than you think it is. In fact in *compiled* code, the name almost doesn't exist. If you want to associate an object with a String, use a Map, or an object with a contiguous number, use an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create dynamic variable names in Java.  I would recommend placing these variables in a Map with a string as a key.  The key can be whatever String you would like.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late. I found another way to get the job done but after a lot of reading that, no, dynamic variables can't be used in Java. I had done it with PHP before and was looking for a similar method. Though Mapping the data using methods like HashMaps would work. As suggested by others. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4):

No this is not possible. It is possible to create a new object and add it to an array or some sort of list. Then you can reference the new object by the subscript.
So a rough example could be:

```
Object[] a = new Object[30]; 

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
a[i] = new Object();
}
```

and then you could use

```
a[some number].someFunction();
```

If you think about it, how can the compiler know what the value of a certain true variable is going to be, outside of the actual program run time? It is unlikely that you need to actually do what you want however.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make an array or a list or a dictionary.

Comment: That isn't really an answer. On the face of it, the OP is asking for some sort of reflection.

Comment: @KerrekSB: This isn't what he's asking for; it's what he actually _needs_.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Use a Dictionary or a Map to store the values.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do such a thing in Java. The closest you could do would be to create code at runtime and load a new class with fields made with dynamic names.

You might want to consider something simpler like a HashMap instance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think reflection will help  because there is no way how to create new instance of Field. So something like

```
Map<String,Field>
```

wont work. Use javascript instead :)