# creating object with a supplied name

Tags: java

I want to do this

```
class DemoClass {

    int money =1000;

    void display() {
        System.out.println("money=" + money);
    }

}

public class createobject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        String objectname = "Harry";
        DemoClass objectname=new DemoClass();//creating object with a supplied name
        System.out.println(Harry.money);//will print 1000
        Harry.display();// will print the same

    }
}
```

it is giving error. Is there any other way that solve the purpose.

Comment: `it is giving error.` - what error do you get? And what do you actually want to achieve? Referencing an object through a dynamically created variable name does not work in Java. Use a `Map` instead.

Comment: despite the fact that this wont work, what do you think should be the benefits of creating a variable with a dynamic name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java variable value as new variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152439/java-variable-value-as-new-variable-name)

Comment: If I want to do so what to do? I have also tried Map but not working ..String objectname = "Harry"; DemoClass name; Map<String, DemoClass> map = new HashMap<>(); map.put(objectname, new DemoClass()); Harry.display();

Answer (score 1):

You must have unique variable names.

Your String variable name and DemoClass variable name both are same--objectname.

Change any one of them.

Also, dynamic variable name wouldn't work in java.

Comment: you can say There aren't any "variable variables" (that is variables with variable names) in Java.

Answer (score 0):

1.Java Basics:You can't have duplicate variables in a method.Here "objectname" is duplicate variable.
2.Harry is not an object,so you can't access any method or variable.You'll get compilation error.

Comment: If I want to do so what to do? I have also tried Map but not working ..String objectname = "Harry";
       DemoClass name;
        Map<String, DemoClass> map = new HashMap<>();
      
        map.put(objectname, new DemoClass());
        
         Harry.display();