# How to add variable value to the name of another variable in java?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make a minecraft plugin. I want it to create variable for every player. I'm using "for" for the loop. I'm trying to add the player's name to the variable's name. Can anyone help?

```
String name = "";
            for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                name = p.getName();
                int cheatdetection+name = 0;
                int looking = (Math.round(p.getLocation().getPitch()) + 270) % 360;
                int currentlooking = looking;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {                      
                    if(looking > currentlooking+20 || looking < currentlooking-20) {
                        cheatdetection+name++;
                    }
                }
                if(cheatdetection >= 10) {
                    Bukkit.getBanList(Type.NAME).addBan(p.getName(), "You have been banned for using Baritone", todate1, "HackMiner Detection");
                    p.kickPlayer("HackMiner Detection");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please share the code and the expected result.

Comment: You don't even provide a vague description of what you want us to help with. At this point, my answer is definitely: no

Comment: if i understand your question.  then you can't do this in java..    this is duplicate please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152439/java-variable-value-as-new-variable-name

Comment: p.getName() returns the player's name. I don't want to make it dynamic. Dynamic variable name will not help me

Comment: why not use composition, create an Object IncidentsForUser having an int nrOfIncidents and a String playerName ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a Map with a key for every player. A Map creates an association between one variable (a key) and another (a value). Values are set using the put(key, value) method, and they retrieved using 'get(key)'

```
// Create an Integer counter for every player, initialized to zero.
Map<Player, Integer> playerCheatCounter = new HashMap<>();
for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
   playerCheatCounter.put(p, 0);
}

// Now to use it:
for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
  int looking = p.getPitch();
  Thread.sleep(10)
  int currentlyLooking = p.getPitch();
  if (looking > currentlyLooking + 20) {
    // Increment counter for the current player
    playerCheatCounter.put(p, 1 + playerCheatCounter.get(p));
    // Check the stored value for the current player
    if (playerCheatCounter.get(p) > 10) {
     // Ban player
    }
  }
 }
```

Edit: Fixed some syntax errors

Comment: Thanks! But if i use Thread.sleep this way it's giving errors. Do you know how to remove the errors?

Comment: Keep the try/catch around your Thread.sleep(). The code above is kind of a summary of what you need to do, not something to copy word-for-word. It does show you how to use a Map though, and that's the important part. Use a loop to initialize values in your map, check the values using get(player), update them with put(player, newValue)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what i need. I asked, because i don't know what try/catch does. But still thank you

Comment: "I asked, because i don't know what try/catch does" - There are tutorials that explain this.  Exceptions and exception handling are a core part of the Java language.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your question;

You want to achieve a for loop where you want to give the variable name as `cheatdetection+name`

The short answer is no, this is not allowed in Java!
Also, as pointed out in the comments, this is what one would call a dynamic variable name.

You could alternatively create a `HashMap`, containing the player name and whatever Object it is that you are trying to store!
This is just a suggestion as it isn't very clear from your question why you need such a variable naming!

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know if i understood your question correctly, since it is very vague and you don't provide any information on what you expect as an outcome. In the fourth line `int cheatdetection+name = 0;` you are attempting to add a String object to a variable name. this is not possible in ANY programming language, since the compiler needs to know the variable name from the start. To fix your problem, you might create a class similar to this:

```
public class PlayerObject {
    private String name;
    private TYPE whateverYouWantToStoreExceptTheName;
    public PlayerObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

If you then make a `List<PlayerObject> list= new ArrayList<>();`, you may always get the player you search for by adding a function like:

```
public PlayerObject getPlayerByName(String name) {
    for(PlayerObject player : list) {
        if(player.getName().equals(name);
            return player;
    return null;
}
```

Be sure to
A: initialize the List before the `for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers())` loop.
B: make a own file for the PlayerObject
C: google how you add, remove and get items from/to the list
D: somehow handle the null in the getPlayerByName function, or you will be stuck with a NullPointerException.